# Loopback 4 delete relation

Tags: relational-database, relation, loopback4

I am staring with lp4, i I have following two models

Product

ProductTranslations

the Product hasMany relation with the ProductTranslations model
How can i delete product, ProductTranslations will be deleted corresponding to product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is [cascade delete](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php). LoopBack 4 does not support this out-of-the-box (see issue [#3526](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/3526)).

As a workaround, you may override the `.delete()` Repository function to start a [Transaction](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Using-database-transactions.html) and emulate a cascade delete with full ACID compliance.

Answer (score -1):

```js
@del('/users/{id}')
  @response(204, {
    description: 'User DELETE success',
  })
  async deleteById(@param.path.string('id') id: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.userRepository.deleteById(id);
  }
```

Comment: The code snippet you have posted doesn't run. Please edit it to a plain code block and add some explanation to your answer.